# How to layer div over everything?

Tags: css

I have a dynamic header that's fixed to the top of all pages. However, when I scroll down, some elements overlap on top of it:

[image: http://d.pr/DJD2]

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Can you show some css and html?

Comment: A code sample would help in diagnosing, but I would guess it is a problem with the z-index on your header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`z-index: 1000` (or a value that's higher than other Z-indexes) in your CSS should work. A browser doesn't only render with X and Y coordinates, there's also a Z which determines which layer goes on top. The `z-index` does this.

You should probably avoid ever using this. A cleaner solution would be to correct the automatic indexing the browser does, by (for example) putting the elements in the right order in your HTML.

Comment: Why is it not advisable to use `z-index`? I have not heard this before.

Answer (score 1):

This would usually be done by giving the element a high `z-index`:

```
#element-id {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```